# How to prove a property of a conditional statement without using tactics in Lean?

Tags: lean, beginner

This doesn't work even though it is the simplest proof of an `if` statement that I can think of:

```
def f [Decidable p] (h : p) : ite p p True := ite p h trivial
```

It says

```
application type mismatch
  ite p h
argument
  h
has type
  p : Prop
but is expected to have type
  if p then p else True : Prop
```

I think it is possible to change the "goal" from `if p then p else True` to `p` using tactics mode, but is it possible to do it without tactics?

The reason I am asking is because I would like to know how to do things without tactics, so that I understand the fundamentals of the language better.

Comment: `ite p h trivial` is a term of type `Prop`, while what you want is a term of type `ite p p True`. I believe what you want are the lemmas `dif_pos` and `dif_neg` (might be called something else in Lean 4).

Comment: @ViHdzP @tydeu "`ite ..` is a term of type `Prop`" is not true, the type of `ite` is whatever the type of both of its branches is. Which means that this `ite` application is not typeable as the two branches have different types, but they *are* proofs, not `Prop`s. Because of proof irrelevance, it never makes sense to apply `ite` to proofs of course.

Comment: Sebastian is correct. I have updated my answer to be more accurate about the types.

Comment: You can use `▸` (aka `Eq.ndrec`) to make the term well typed: `example (p : Prop) [Decidable p] : ite p p True := dite p (fun h => if_pos h ▸ h) (fun h => if_neg h ▸ trivial)`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `ite` to branch on `p` you want to use `match` on the `Decidable p` instance like so:

```
def f [d : Decidable p] (h : p) : ite p p True :=
  match d with
  | isTrue _ => h 
  | isFalse _ => trivial
```

As Sebastian notes in his comment, `ite p h trivial` is an ill-typed term (`h` is of type `p` and `True` is of type `Prop`. And as ViHdzP notes, what we want is to produce a term of type `ite p p True`.

To see why are the above solution works, consider the parallel proof with tactics:

```
def f' [d : Decidable p] (h : p) : ite p p True := by
  unfold ite -- ⊢ Decidable.casesOn d (fun x => True) fun x => p
  cases d with
  | isTrue _ => -- ⊢ Decidable.casesOn (isTrue h✝) (fun x => True) fun x => p
    dsimp -- ⊢ p
    exact h -- Goals accomplished 
  | isFalse _ => -- ⊢ Decidable.casesOn (isFalse h✝) (fun x => True) fun x => p
    dsimp -- Goals accomplished  -- reduces to True and thus closes the goal
```